# Triangle-based and vertex-based skinning models?

Tags: 3d, mesh, animation

I'm reading the Loper et al. 2015 paper on the Skinned Multi-Person Linear Model and I came across this:

> What we would like is a vertex-based model that has the expressive
>   power of the triangle deformation models so that it can capture
>   a whole range of natural shapes and poses.

I'm not a Computer Science student, I'm actually a Physics student, so I only have an elementary understanding of these matters.

What is the difference between a triangle-based and a vertex-based skinning model? 
Why is the triangle-based one more "expressive"?

Comment: And these terms aren't adressed anywhere in the paper?

Comment: Not in a meaningful way. The paper deals with a vertex based model (the equations and the logic behind it describe the deformation of the mesh in terms of the displacement of the vertices) but it doesn't discuss triangle-based models. I can only guess what they're about. Moreover I don't know why triangle-based models would be more "expressive" than vertex-based ones.

Comment: They are cited from this paper:  http://people.csail.mit.edu/sumner/research/deftransfer/Sumner2004DTF.pdf

Comment: @Wyck so the expressiveness of triangle-based models is just a practical fact, there is no mathematical or computational reason